# Page indicator does not work in android image slide

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I create an image slide for android
this app is working correctly but when I use this code in other app the page indicator does not work.

when I click "home" mobile button and select this app page indicator state is updating

this app uses a library and this library uses android v4 support

Comment: Consider reading stackoverflow's http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to know how to ask a good question

Comment: I've flagged this as "unclear what you're asking". Please edit your question with a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and an explanation of what you expect the app to do and what it does instead.